# How to Host a webpage on my Localhost and intercept responses in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, httplistener

So at the moment I am hosting some HTML code on my localhost using a httplistener in VB.NET. Here is the code for that:

```
Shared httpListener As HttpListener = New HttpListener()

Private Shared Sub Main()
    Debug.WriteLine("Starting server...")
    httpListener.Prefixes.Add("localhost:5000/")
    httpListener.Start()
    Debug.WriteLine("Server started.")
    Dim _responseThread As Thread = New Thread(AddressOf ResponseThread)
    _responseThread.Start()
End Sub

Private Shared Sub ResponseThread()
    While True
        Dim context As HttpListenerContext = httpListener.GetContext()
        Dim responseArray As Byte() = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("<html><script src=""https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js"">async defer</script><div class=""g-recaptcha"" data-sitekey=""sitekey""></div></html>")
        context.Response.OutputStream.Write(responseArray, 0, responseArray.Length)
        context.Response.KeepAlive = False
        context.Response.Close()
        Debug.WriteLine("Respone given to a request.")
    End While
End Sub
```

Now this works perfectly and notifies me whenever a request is made to the localhost, but I want to be able to receive response data when a user (me) does the recaptcha. I am not sure how to do this and have looked everywhere. So any help is appreciated, I tried seeing if I could get responses using the httplistenerresponse but had no look and even looked into TCP clients and listeners. There is probably an easier way to do this, and any help is appreciated.

Fiddler is a prime example of what I need my program to do, but just listen to the response after completing the captcha.

Thanks!

Comment: I know for a fact node.js has a really simple web server which can do this, So if a user enters a subdomain it will send a response to the application and give them a response, clearly in vb.net this is a lot harder. probably not impossible but I can't find a way to do this.